# Python: how to conceal input

Tags: python

How do you conceal the input of `raw_input`? For example, I want:

```
password = raw_input("Password: ")
```

To be

```
Password: ********
#or
Password: #hide the characters (i.e. no echo)
```

Instead of displaying the string. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`getpass`**](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/getpass.html):

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
```